# Pattern matchin using regex in grep in end of line

Tags: regex

I have a file, let's say abc.txt, which contains below kind of data:

```
AB8PDSYU_DFRH

AB8PDSPO_RET

AB8PDSYT_DPRO

AB0PDSTR_GHRJT

AB0PDSQW_GTJY
```

My expected output is just to be in format `A{either B0 or B8}PDS{exactly 2 char}_{exactly 4 char}`, as per this rule, my output should be only:

```
AB8PDSYU_DFRH

AB8PDSYT_DPRO

AB0PDSQW_GTJY
```

I am using the below grep command:

```
grep -E '^A(B0|B8)PDS[[:alpha:]]{2}_[[:alpha:]]{4}' abc.txt
```

and getting output:

```
AB8PDSYU_DFRH

AB8PDSYT_DPRO

AB0PDSTR_GHRJT

AB0PDSQW_GTJY
```

I have mentioned `[[:alpha:]]{4}`, which ideally should match exactly 4 alphabets only. But, it is not working like this and giving me **AB0PDSTR_GHRJT** as well in the output.

Please let me know what I am missing here.

Comment: Add an anchor `$` to assert the end of the string. `grep -E '^A(B0|B8)PDS[[:alpha:]]{2}_[[:alpha:]]{4}$' abc.txt` You could shorten the alternation to a character class `^AB[08]PDS[[:alpha:]]{2}_[[:alpha:]]{4}$`

Comment: `^A(B0|B8)PDS[[:alpha:]]{2}_[[:alpha:]]{4}$`.. missing `$`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a way to detect that you want nothing more after for your match, or else it matches a part of the line, like `$` to precise the end of the string, or `[[:space]]` (equivalent to `\s`) for any whitespace.

I'm no expert in grep, depending on if it treats it multiline or not, one of these should work:

```
^A(B0|B8)PDS[[:alpha:]]{2}_[[:alpha:]]{4}$
^A(B0|B8)PDS[[:alpha:]]{2}_[[:alpha:]]{4}($|[[:space]])
```

Comment: `\b` can be used too

Comment: @rock321987 yes it should, but I had some troubles with it in the past, I think it was with unicode accented characters